# How to save the image directly from PictureBox without stored procedure with Dapper in Windows Form Application with Dapper?

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio, dapper, windows-forms-designer

I used the stored procedure for saving *pic* to *db* before, now I want to save it without the stored procedure
is possible to directly save from `PictureBox`?

```
private void buttonsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Categoryentity categoryentity = new Categoryentity();
    categoryentity.CategoryName = texboxcatname.Text;
    categoryentity.Description = textBoxcatdesc.Text;
    categoryentity.Picture = pictureBox1.Image;
    Dbclass dbclass = new Dbclass();

    long result = dbclass.insertcategory(categoryentity);
    if (result > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("inserted");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("failed");
    }
}

private void buttonuploadpic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //string imagelocation = "";
    //try
    //{
    OpenFileDialog fdialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    fdialog.Filter = "jpg files(*.jpg)|*.jpg| PNG files(*.png)|*.png| All Files(*.*)|*.*";

    if (fdialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        imagelocation = fdialog.FileName.ToString();
        pictureBox1.ImageLocation = imagelocation;
    }
}
```

entity class

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Dapper.Contrib.Extensions;

namespace Northwind.Entities
{
    [Table ("Categories")]
  public   class Categoryentity
    {

        public int CategoryID { get; set; }

        public string CategoryName { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public string Pic { get; set; }

        public Image Picture { get; set; }
```

insertion fn

```
 public class Dbclass
    {
       
        public long insertcategory(Categoryentity categoryentity)
        {
            using (var connection = DBLayer.ConnectionFactory())
            {
                long id = connection.Insert<Categoryentity>(categoryentity);
                return id;

            }
        }
```

I can upload the image, but I don't know how to insert it properly. but when I was using the stored procedure, it was inserted successfully.

previous stored procedure

```
byte[] images = null;
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(imagelocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fileStream);
images = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)fileStream.Length);

Dbclass dbclass = new Dbclass();

string maincon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(maincon);

sqlcon.Open();
string query = "insert into Categories(CategoryName,Description,Picture) Values ('" + texboxcatname.Text + "','" + textBoxcatdesc.Text + "',@images)";

SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlcon);
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@images", images));
int N = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlcon.Close();
MessageBox.Show("saved");
```

Comment: Is this giving any error? Can you please share your code with stored procedure? so stored procedure also are you using dapper?

Comment: you can refer this https://dapper-tutorial.net/execute#example-execute-insert

Comment: no sir i mean i want to insert without stored procedure , is it possible? @viveknuna

Comment: you don't want to write a query also? why don't you want to use the stored procedure? any reasons?

Comment: i just used normal stored procedure before

Comment: i think its will be simple for me to do further operations like update ,delete etc @viveknuna

Comment: my stored procedure is too long , i can't write it here!! @viveknuna

Comment: @ Vishnu Kumar. What is the Data Type of the Picture in your database table? Is it image, varbinary (MAX) or other types? And are you considering converting image to byte[] and storing it in the database? Converting between byte[] and image is a good common choice.

Comment: @HuiLiu-MFST. data type is 'image' . and i already try use a fn to convert timage into binary , but its not worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For directly inserting the picturebox picture into the data table and reading the picture from the data table to the picturebox, you could try to refer to the following code.

```
using Dapper.Contrib.Extensions;
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace insertimage
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Add();
            MessageBox.Show("saved");
        }
        internal void Add()
        {
            string constr = @"constr";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            string sqlinsert = "insert into  [dbo].[Category] ([Id],[Name],[Picture]) values (@Id,@Name,@Picture) ";
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlinsert, con);
            byte[] b;
            Image img = pictureBox1.Image;
            using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                img.Save(mStream, img.RawFormat);
                b = mStream.ToArray();
            }
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", texboxcatid.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", textBoxcatdesc.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Picture", b);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string constr = @"constr";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            string sql = "select * from  [dbo].[Category]";
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            byte[] by = null;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                by = (byte[])reader[2];
            }
            Image img = byteArrayToImage(by);
            pictureBox2.Image = img;
        }
        public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] bytesArr)
        {
            using (MemoryStream memstr = new MemoryStream(bytesArr))
            {
                Image img = Image.FromStream(memstr);
                return img;
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog fdialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            fdialog.Filter = "jpg files(*.jpg)|*.jpg| PNG files(*.png)|*.png| All Files(*.*)|*.*";

            if (fdialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(fdialog.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                Image im = Image.FromStream(fs);
                pictureBox1.Image = im;
            }
        }
    }
    [Table("Category")]
    public class Category
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Image Picture { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The result :
[image]

Comment: . Thankyou so much Sir, insertion success , but my intend is to display it into a gridview . i use fn convertbinaryto image, but still display only image icon in gridview , not the picture !,,,may i get yr whsap.no?

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper.Contrib/.

And then use the below code to insert the record

```
Categoryentity obj = new Categoryentity ();
...
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    return conn.Insert(obj) ;
}
```

Comment: Thanyou sir @Vivek

Comment: not really sir , i already installed dapper pachages ,and my connection string is declared on ' appconfig ' , and i use connection as  
            `Dbclass dbclass = new Dbclass();

            long result = dbclass.insertcategory(categoryentity);
            if (result > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("inserted");

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("failed");
            }
`

Comment: but i don't know how to get the pic pfrom picturebox   
            `Categoryentity categoryentity = new Categoryentity();
            categoryentity.CategoryName = texboxcatname.Text;
            categoryentity.Description = textBoxcatdesc.Text;
            categoryentity.Picture = pictureBox1.Image;
`
              i declared as this

Comment: @VishnuKumar you said, it was working for you with SP?

Comment: yes sir it's worked with that stored procedure i mentioned on above code part,  but now i'm trying to save it directly , is there any way to convert image from picturebox to binary string  ,, i tried a fn for convertimagetobinary , but its not worked  @Vivek nuna

Answer (score 0):

we can use this code to insert picture from picturebox

before that declate image type as byte[] on entity class.

on buttonsave action

```
 private void buttonSavemp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 empentity.PhotoPath = textBoxphotopath.Text;

            Image image = pictureBoxphoto.Image;
            byte[] data;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                data = ms.ToArray();
            }

            empentity.Photo = data;
     Dbclass dbclass = new Dbclass();
            long result = dbclass.insertpicture(empentity);

            if (result > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("inserted succesfully");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("insertion failed");
            }
```

and we can use the below code for get picture

```
 System.Drawing.ImageConverter imageConverter = new System.Drawing.ImageConverter();
                Image image = (Image)imageConverter.ConvertFrom(employeentity.Photo);
                pictureBoxphoto.Image = image;
```